# What is the 'import * as ...' equivalent for require?

Tags: node.js, import, require

When using the ES6 `import` command, you can use an alias to import all functions from a file, for example:

```
import * as name from "module-name";
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this using require, i.e.:

```
const { * as name } = require('module-name');
```

Comment: I believe it would be simply `const name = require("module-name");` although I'm not using ancient tech.

Comment: require (CommonJS) and import (ES6 modules) are two different types of modules system, they don't work together

Comment: I'm not sure about that, we've been using precompilation for years now (we use TypeScript, but babel ES6 would work as well).

Comment: using typescript is not the same as supporting ES6 modules natively, typescript compiles into commonjs in node. there are many open questions with support of es6 modules in Node

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard They may work together in some cases

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to import all functions from a file using require() by using the * as syntax. Here's an example:

```
const name = require('module-name');

// Import all functions from 'module-name' and assign them to the 'name' object
const { *: name } = require('module-name');
```

In the above example, the * syntax is used to import all functions from the module-name file, and the as keyword is used to assign them to the name object.

It's worth noting that while the * as syntax works for both import and require, it is generally considered better practice to import only the functions that you actually need. This can help to reduce the size of your code and make it easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score -2):

```
const name = require('moduleName.js');
```

This means that when you have (moduleName.js)...

```
function foo(){
    ...
}

module.exports = { foo };
```

...the `foo()` function can be accessed by another file using:

```
const name = require('moduleName.js');
name.foo();
```